# Errors while testing a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and I'm trying to test my app.

In my sample app, I have in user_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    def test_truth 
        assert true
    end
end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Z:\web\rails\pbbg\test>ruby unit/user_test.rb
c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependenci
es.rb:105:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Test::Unit::TestResult::Tes
tResultFailureSupport (NameError)
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/test-unit-2.0.3/lib/test/unit/testre
sult.rb:28
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `ge
m_original_require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `re
quire'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/test-unit-2.0.3/lib/test/unit/ui/tes
trunnermediator.rb:9
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `ge
m_original_require'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `re
quire'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_suppo
rt/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
         ... 6 levels...
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:214:in `run'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit/autorunner.rb:12:in `run'
        from c:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/test/unit.rb:278
        from unit/user_test.rb:3
```

I can't find what I've done wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears to be something to do with the gem version of test-unit you have installed.  You could `gem uninstall test-unit` to see if that helps - test-unit is included with ruby itself.  Otherwise you might want to include your `test/test_helper.rb`, that might have something in it causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails includes test-unit. If you also have the Test-unit gem installed, you will get a conflict between the two. Simply uninstall the gem and your tests should start working.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've installed a too new version of test-unit. Try uninstalling it, that should fix your issue.